# Portable Writer-Readers spinlock

Tags: c++, boost, spinlock

I used `boost::shared_mutex` as synchronization objects in Writer-Readers model. However, it's considerably slow compared with no locks used (In my test: without any readers, to write 500,000 values it takes 100 msec if no locks used and ~500 msec if `boost::shared_mutex` used). That's why I decided to consider something like spinlock. I would like to make a portable spinlock (Windows + Linux).

1. Is there any boost wrapper that I can use instantly?
2. [This](https://jfdube.wordpress.com/2014/01/03/implementing-a-recursive-read-write-spinlock/) is a good topic that shows how to implement spinlock on Windows. But I was unable to find out equivalents of Win32 APIs such as `InterlockedCompareExchange`, `YieldProcessor`, `InterlockedDecrement` on Linux.

**Update 2016/03/08**

I found out a [guide](http://locklessinc.com/articles/locks/) and the [implementation](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/RWSpinLock.h) released by facebook on github. Haven't tried it yet. I updated here for anyone who will have the same question and might want to refer.

Comment: If you have more writers than readers, using a shared mutex is foolish. They're for cases where you want to make the readers fast at the expense of making the comparatively rare write operation slower. Try using ordinary mutexes.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have only 1 writer and up to 16 readers.

Comment: Then why do you care how it performs with no readers?!

Comment: Also, don't follow the advice in the article you linked to. It has poor performance. For example, the `LockWriter` code has this: `while(Lock & 0x7fffffff); return;`. Well that's just great. If there's contention, and you do spin, when you finally get the write lock and are blocking all other threads that want the synchronization object and it's imperative you execute as quickly as possible, you take the mother of all mispredicted branches and blow out the pipelines. That's all wrong.

Comment: Are you using c++11 or later ? std::atomic<bool> will provide a simple spinlock.

Comment: @Jojje Yes, but with *atrocious* performance.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am implementing Writer so there haven't any readers now. That's why I said "without readers".

Comment: @Jojje No, I target to c++03 + boost library.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Also, in the article, the author has improved by replacing while(Lock & 0x7fffffff) return; by while(Lock & 0x80000000) YieldProcessor();

Comment: @duong_dajgja Which he suggests only matters if you have hyper-threading, which is incorrect. But in any event, the point is that you should never implement your own synchronization primitives unless you have an urgent need and/or deep platform-specific understanding of precisely what your code makes the CPU do. And you shouldn't care how they perform under unrealistic conditions.

Answer (score 1):

1. There exists no portable solution for C++03 because C++03 has no memory model but you can implement it very easily by just copying `atomic_flag` implementations of your target platform.
2. My comment for the given link/tutorial: `volatile` should not be used by an application programmer unless you access unusual memory. I recommend [this](http://preshing.com/20150316/semaphores-are-surprisingly-versatile/) and all others articles of that topic. There should be a ready to use library for download. I do not know if it is C++11 only.
3. I assume you are not very experienced with multithreading, synchronization and locks. Whatever you want to achieve, just go the standard route first and came back later if your performance is not enough.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. I am a newbie. I think I'd better stick to shared mutex and see the performance in real environment first. Thank you sir!